# Permalink Issues by Installing WordPress in Subdirectory / Subfolder

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, directory, installation, wp-config

I installed WP in subfolder `/cms` and it runs live without subfolder. When I use `/%postname%/` as permalink I get 404 error on my site. My Server supported `mod_rewrite`.

## My Code

*wp-config.php*

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.sitename.de/cms');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.sitename.de');
```

#### root

*1) .htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cms/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*2) index.php*

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('./cms/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

#### /cms

*1) .htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*2) index.php*

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Answer (score 3):

What I generally do

- Install WP in sub directory.
- Open permalink set required permalink.
- Open settings->general link
- Remove the sub directory name from 'Site Address (URL)'
- Cut the index.php and .htaccess files from sub directory and paste them to root
- change code in index.php as you did.
- Again access settings->permalink save the form

Done. You dont need index.php and .htaccess file in sub directory.

Comment: Strange enough, this goes against what's in the codex [Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). There they say to keep a copy of both `index.php` and `.htaccess`. Any hint on this?  

Please note: I'm not an `.htaccess` expert, and there's still something not clear about how should those file look in each folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and issue was not in code but was in httpd file

1. Open the Apache configuration file located at/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (or apache.conf for ubuntu)
2. Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All inside the DocumentRoot Directory
   Directive, normally

Comment: This saved my day. When usual instruction does not work something fishy goes around. I guess this should be added to the codex manual about changing to subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

my solution to this problem, wich always works in my case;

create a .htaccess file in the subdirectory and add the code wich is generated when you change the permalinks on the bottom of the page.

example of the generated code;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kimco/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /kimco/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you saying that both `.htaccess` files (in root and subdir) should have the same contents? E.g. both with `RewriteBase /kimco/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the .htaccess file under /cms and then visit Settings -> Permalinks to flush your rewrite rules.  Also make sure the site URL and home URL are set up in the database correctly (like you have in the wp-config).

Comment: if you define site and home url in wp-config, whatever is in the database will be ignored

Comment: @Milo: Thats right  
When I refresh my permalinks (wp admin-area), root .htaccess looks like: .. `RewriteBase /` ... `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` but I think it should looks like: ... `RewriteBase /cms` ... `RewriteRule . /cms/index.php [L]`

Comment: in the root, i think it should look like `RewriteBase /` as it apparently does after refreshing permalinks. Did that solve it ?